# Levelhelper sprite + SneakyJoystick

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone, joystick, d-pad

Basically i'd like to move a box2d body of a LHSprite that I created using [LevelHelper](http://www.gamedevhelper.com/products/levelhelper/).
I have tried moving the box2d body of the LHSprite, based on weather my SneakyJoystick is active (that part works fine) with the following code:

```
if(dpad.leftJoystick.velocity.x > 0){
    b2Vec2 force;
    force.Set(dpad.leftJoystick.velocity.x * 10.0f, 0.0f);
    Player.body->ApplyForce(force, Player.body->GetPosition());
}
```

Can anyone see how I can get this working?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

LHSPrite has these methods:
[sprite transformPosition:ccp(50,50)]; //will set the sprite position to 50,50 together with the physical body
[sprite transformRotation:240];//will rotate the sprite to angle 240, together with the physical body

you have to update LHSPrite postitions bassed on box2d body in update method (see examples).